# jetty server HttpConnection IllegalStateException: s=DISPATCHED i=true a=null

Tags: jetty

this is my first question on stackoverflow, so, im not very clear the rule of it..

my server got a error on jetty. this error often appear when a lot of request to the server.

the error is:

```java
09-24 01:45:40.091 [qtp1379435698-982] WARN  org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:265) - HttpConnection@6ddcef89{FILLING}
java.lang.IllegalStateException: s=DISPATCHED i=true a=null
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannelState.handling(HttpChannelState.java:231)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:282)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:245)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

after a lot of this error appear, the jetty has restarted.
the jetty version is 9.2.7.v20150116.

I am very much looking forward to your answer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! If you unsure how or what to ask, please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). After that, you can edit your question.

Comment: Update your version of Jetty and try again. (There are 23 minor version updates since 9.2.7 within the now EOL 9.2.x line)

Comment: ok, i will try, thank you